# C++ Getting address of substring

Tags: c++, string

Let's say I have 2 strings `S1 = "zzzzabra"` and `S2 = "abracadabra"`.

I want to know, for example, if `S1[4:8]` is a prefix of `S2`.

Ok, I can just get the substring `S1.substr(4,4)` and pass to some prefix test function.

But the problem is: as I won't change the string, I wouldn't like to pass a copy, but just an address of where it begins, for example.

Is it possible? If I had some comparison function `cmpPrefix(string &s1, string  &s2)`, for example, what should I pass to it if I wanted to check if `S1[4:8]` is prefix of `S2`?

I will do this comparison operation lots of times and I think I shouldn't waste time with unnecessary copies. Also I want to keep the code clean, so at first I don't want to put a lot of parameters in the function to do this trick.

Comment: You could pass a pointer to where it begins, and how many characters it is, like C.

Comment: Yeah, but as I said, at first I'd like only that 2 parameters if it's possible... if it's not possible to do this trick this way, I'll add some parameters to it

Comment: @Daniel: If you only want 2 parameters, then how should the function know about 4 or 8? Or do you want 4 and 8 to be hard-coded within the function?

Comment: You will pretty much need 3 parameters in your case. Source, target and character count. Unless you're trying to have your function match an old codebase, don't push yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string str1 = "abcdwgyz";
string str2 = "wxyzpqrs";

return (str1.compare(4, 4, str2.substr(0, 4)) == 0);
```

Comment: `substr` is not needed: `return (str1.compare(4, 4, str2, 0, 4) == 0);`

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is: as I won't change the string, I wouldn't like to
>   pass a copy, but just an address of where it begins, for example.

First of all, that's premature optimisation. Don't worry so much about copy semantics.

Second, think in terms of iterators, not addresses. Once you realise that you can get random-access iterators to string elements with functions like `begin()` and `end()`, the whole arsenal of standard C++ algorithms is at your disposal.

[`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) sounds like what you need. Here is an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string const S1 = "zzzzabra";
    std::string const S2 = "abracadabra";

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    auto const result = std::search(
        begin(S2),
        end(S2),
        begin(S1) + 4,
        begin(S1) + 8
    );

    if (result == begin(S2))
    {
        std::cout << "prefix\n";
    }
}
```

---

Note that due to the generic nature of `std::search`, `std::begin` and `std::end`, this even works with `char const[]`:

```
char const S1[] = "zzzzabra";
char const S2[] = "abracadabra";
```

Answer (score 0):

C function: strstr(), maybe check strcmp() [**from C**]

C++ String function: compare()

They both takes just the address.

**Make sure to convert your C++ string to C String using c_str().**

Comment: I tried to use compare a few times but it was just returning me -1 no matter what I gave as parameter. How can I use compare to check if `S1[4:8]` is prefix of `S2` ? does it deal the case where `S1 > S2` ?

Comment: try strcmp() from C.

Make sure to convert C++ string to C string; they are not the same!!

Comment: strcmp() from C does deal with >, < or ==